# Array of ArrayList

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;
class A
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList arrayOfArrayList[]=new ArrayList[2];
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
            arrayOfArrayList[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        }
        arrayOfArrayList[0].add(1);
        arrayOfArrayList[0].add(2);
        arrayOfArrayList[1].add(3);
        arrayOfArrayList[1].add(4);
        Integer arr[][] = new Integer[2][];
        arr[0] = arrayOfArrayList[0].toArray(arr[0]);
        arr[1] = arrayOfArrayList[1].toArray(arr[1]);
        for (Integer x : arr[0])
            System.out.print(x + " ");
    }
}
```

I am trying to create an array of arrayLists and later convert it to array.
But the compile time error
error: Incompatible type conversion object[] to Integer[]

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Comment: In addition to avoiding raw types you will have to change toArray(arr[0]) to toArray(new Integer[0])) to avoid a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

Here you created [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) :

```
ArrayList arrayOfArrayList[]=new ArrayList[2];
```

If you need to store `Integer` there, you should use correct generics:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrayOfArrayList[]=new ArrayList[2];
```

Comment: But it is giving a warning unchecked conversion required List<Integer>[]  found: ArrayList[]

Comment: yes, `new ArrayList<Integer>[2]` will not compile. You should reconsider you data structure. Currently it seems pretty horrible to work with.